# how to update order list using input text keyword

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have cars object and one input field on change I want to switch order of cars

Let's say I put inside input box Tau then ford object should be before Nissan INSIDE CAR object and Nissan object should move after Ford How this possible Please guide

```
 {
        "cars": {
            "Nissan": [
                {"model":"Sentra", "doors":4},
                {"model":"Maxima", "doors":4},
                {"model":"Skyline", "doors":2}
            ],
            "Ford": [
                {"model":"Taurus", "doors":4},
                {"model":"Escort", "doors":4}
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is idea how you can do it

```
const data = {
    "cars": {
        "Nissan": [
            {"model":"Sentra", "doors":4},
            {"model":"Maxima", "doors":4},
            {"model":"Skyline", "doors":2}
        ],
        "Ford": [
            {"model":"Taurus", "doors":4},
            {"model":"Escort", "doors":4}
        ]
    }
}

const inputValue = 'Tau'
const d = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))

Object.keys(d.cars).forEach(item =>{
  if(JSON.stringify(d.cars[item]).search(inputValue) > -1){
    console.log('move up logic')
  }
})
```